# Sliding Panel .stop() not working on $(this).next

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple boxes and when hovering over a sliding panel should slide out of the one you are hovering over.  I have it working without the sliding panel stopping when over the panel which can be seen here:

https://jsfiddle.net/r70nbL8t/3/

```
$('.clickable_div').mouseover( function(){
$(this).next('.nav_menu').slideDown();
})
$('.clickable_div').mouseleave( function(){
$(this).next('.nav_menu').slideUp();
});
```

But when I introduce the stop, the panel doesn't slide anymore

https://jsfiddle.net/r70nbL8t/4/

```
$(".wrap").mouseover(function(){
$(this).next(".nav_menu").stop().slideDown("slow");
});
$(".wrap").mouseout(function(){
$(this).next('.nav_menu').slideUp();
});
```

I must be doing something simple wrong.  Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you exec `$(this).next()` return element `p`, You should use `find()` function

```
$(".wrap").mouseover(function(){
   $(this).find(".nav_menu").stop().slideDown("slow");
});

$(".wrap").mouseout(function(){
   $(this).find('.nav_menu').slideUp();
});
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/r70nbL8t/5/